# Comparing two definitions for an open set in a topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathcal{b}$ be a base for a topological space.

I am comparing the definition for open in my class notes to the definition for open in my textbook:

1. We call $A \subseteq X$ *open* if and only if $A$ is some union of elements from $\mathcal{b}$.
2. We call $A \subseteq X$ open if for every $x \in A,$ there is a basis element $B \in \mathcal{b}$ such that $x \in B \subseteq A.$

I am trying to show that these definitions are the same:

$1 \Rightarrow 2:$ If $A$ is a union of base elements (i.e. $A = \bigcup_{\omega \in \Omega}B_{\omega}$ ) then if $x \in A \Rightarrow$ then $x \in B_{\omega} \subset A$ for some $\omega.$

$2 \Rightarrow 1:$ If every element $x_{\omega} \in A$ belongs to some base $B_{\omega} \in \mathcal{b}$ for some index $\omega \in \Omega,$ then $A$ is clearly a union of base elements.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: 2=>1 is not convincing.

Comment: I feel the same... What are some details I can add? I'm having trouble and I know it's probably really easy

Comment: @Alwayslearning For $x \in A$ let $B_x \in b$ be some such that $x \in B_x \subseteq A$. This exists by (2). Then $\bigcup_{x \in A} B_x = A$. In your $2 \Rightarrow 1$ it is not clear what the indexing set $\Omega$ is and the way you wrote it you did not argue why the union is exactly $A$.

Comment: @AlešBizjak Thank you for the help

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a base for a topological space $X$.

(1) implies (2): Suppose $A$ is open for definition (1). So there is a collection $\mathcal{B}' \subseteq \mathcal{B}$ such that $A = \cup \mathcal{B}'$. Now to see that $A$ is open according to (2): let $x \in A$ be arbitrary. Then by the definition of union, for some $B \in \mathcal{B}'$ we have that $x \in B$. Clearly $B \subseteq \mathcal{B}' = A$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}$. So $A$ is open wrt definition (2).

(2) implies (1): Suppose $A$ is open for definition (1). Then for each $x \in A$, we pick, according to this definition, $B_x \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B_x \subseteq A$. Then we claim that $A = \cup \{ B_x: x \in A \}$. Both inclusions are clear: every $x \in A$ is in its "own" $B_x$, so in the union, and every set in the union is a subset of $A$, so the union is too. Then we have written $A$ as a union of a subfamily of $\mathcal{B}$ so $A$ is open according to $A$.